# Как организовать href, чтобы не терялся аргумент, к которому есть параметр?

Tags: html, веб-программирование

Есть html страница по данному адресу: `localhost:9292/schools/lyceum/8?order=straight`
Так же есть кнопка,

```
<a href="classes/10208177" class="button">К классу</a>
```

Вот так задаётся кнопка для перехода на страницу localhost:9292/schools/lyceum/8?order=straight

```
<a href="/schools/lyceum/8?order=straight/" class="button">lyceum</a>
```

Проблема в том, что кнопка перекидывает на `localhost:9292/schools/lyceum/classes/10208177`, то есть, в данном случае, `8` теряется. Как мне организовать `href`, чтобы `8` не потерялась? То есть открылось `localhost:9292/schools/lyceum/8/classes/10208177`, либо `localhost:9292/schools/lyceum/8?order=straight/classes/10208177`

Comment: никто вам не даст ответа, не зная с чем и в чем вы там вообще работаете. найдите переменную, которая содержит нужный id и постройте ссылку вручную целиком.  мб какой нить `school_class.school_id` или что там за данные у вас есть еще

Comment: @teran Исправил. Это просто переменная, содержащая некоторое числовое значение. Пример был в ссылках снизу.